# Problem related to Bolzano Weierstrass theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $a_n$, let $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | a_m > a_n,\forall m > n\}$.

(a) If $S$ is infinite, then show that there is an increasing function $n : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n(k)}$ is a monotone increasing sub-sequence of $a_n$.

(b) If $S$ is finite, then show that there is an increasing function $n : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n(k)}$ is a monotone non-increasing $a_{n(k)} \geq a_{n(k+1)}$ subsequence of $a_n$.

Can anyone help me with solving this question?

I know it is somewhat related to Bolzano Weierstrass theorem proof, but I am new in mathematics field and I am getting trouble in writing the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Let $S=\{n(1),n(2),n(3),....\}$ with $n(1)<n(2) <n(3)<....$. Since $n(+1)>n(k)$, we get (from the definition of $S$):

$a_{n(k+1)} > a_{n(k)}$.

(b) There is $q \in \mathbb N$ such that $\{q,q+1,q+2,... \} \subseteq \mathbb N \setminus S$.

Now let $n(k):q+k-1$ for $k \in \mathbb N$.

It is your turn to show that

$a_{n(k)} \geq a_{n(k+1)}$.